# Access - SELECT JOIN many to many 2 tables with 3 dictionaries

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, relationships

please help me with ACCESS SQL SELECT query.

[Database scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG4hg.png)

I need to link Sales data into my Promo table. See the scheme above.
I try somethink like this, but it doesn't work.

```
       SELECT P.Ext_item_id, P.Ext_shop_id, P.Ext_date_id, S.SALES

       FROM (((PromoTable AS P INNER JOIN SHOP AS SH ON P.Ext_shop_id = SH.Ext_shop_id)
                               INNER JOIN ITEM AS I ON P.Ext_item_id = I.Ext_item_id)
                               INNER JOIN DATE AS D ON P.Ext_date_id = D.Ext_date_id)

                          ?????INNER JOIN SALES AS S ON SH.shop_id=S.shop_id
                                                    AND I.item_id = S.item_id
                                                    AND D.date_id = D.date_id
```

The question is: how to link 2 tables using 3 dictionary tables beetween them (M:M relationship)
Great thanks in advance!

### Examples of data in tables

[Tables view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qj2Q.png)

Comment: How does it now work?

Comment: It doesn't work at all. Because i'm JOINing SALES table with keys from another table. I need to join somehow PROMO -> ITEMS -> SALES etc

Comment: Well, there's at least one typo in your code - the last line should be `D.date_id = S.date_id`. Are you sure you got the database design right? Three intermediate tables with different key pairs doesn't seem like a right way to implement a M:M relationship. Could you elaborate on your goal a little?

Comment: Ok, describing what i do. There is DB with SALES. I need to do my own DB with PROMO analytics. In order to do it i want to prepare QUERY with all data from my PROMO table (like % discount, plan sales on promo etc) and match it with data from SALES table, but IDs are different howether there are 3 tables for ITEMS, DATES and Shops - dictionary tables with different information like Item Name, Item hierarchy, Shop region etc, and these tables contain also accordance between 2 different ID types.

Comment: Need examples of data for each table, to be honest..

Comment: I added examples of data in my tables

Comment: Please add data to the body of your question and not as screenshot as we cannot use it for a reproducible example. Help us help you. Also, are you allowed to change database schema as some recommendations can be made for proper [normalization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial approach seems correct..

```
  SELECT P.Ext_item_id, P.Ext_shop_id, P.Ext_date_id, S.SALES
  FROM PROMO P
  INNER JOIN SHOP SH ON P.Ext_shop_id = SH.Ext_shop_id
  INNER JOIN ITEM I ON P.Ext_item_id = I.Ext_item_id
  INNER JOIN [DATE] D ON P.Ext_date_id = D.Ext_date_id
  INNER JOIN SALES S 
    ON SH.shop_id=S.shop_id  AND I.item_id = S.item_id  AND D.date_id = S.date_id
```

Comment: Hi @MiroslavAtanasov if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.